# LINQ Entity don't generate valid MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, debugging, linq-to-entities

Hi i am having issues using Linq when working on a database

```
var acks = (from a in db.eventsandacks
                    where a.triggerDate.Month == 1 && a.joinedrcat > 5 
                    && a.customerName == "CUSTOMER"
                    group a by new { a.triggerDate.Day } into b
                    orderby b.Key.Day
                    select new
                    {
                        Day = b.Key.Day,
                        Count = b.Count()
                    });
```

The funny part is that it works if i only read out Day or Count but not both at the same time. When i run both i get this error.

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unknown column 'GroupBy1.K1' in 'field list'
  at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()
  at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow, Int64& insertedId)
  at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.GetResult(Int32 statementId, Int32& affected Rows, Int64& insertedId)
  at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean force)

  at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()
  at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
  at MySql.Data.Entity.EFMySqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
  at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
  at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
```

the generated SQL looks like this.

```
{SELECT
`Project1`.`C3` AS `C1`, 
`Project1`.`C2`, 
`Project1`.`C1` AS `C3`
FROM (SELECT
`GroupBy1`.`A1` AS `C1`, 
`GroupBy1`.`K1` AS `C2`, 
1 AS `C3`
FROM (SELECT
COUNT(1) AS `A1`
FROM `eventsandack` AS `Extent1`
 WHERE ((1 = (MONTH(`Extent1`.`triggerDate`))) AND     (`Extent1`.`joinedrcat` > 5)) AND ('CUSTOMER' = `Extent1`.`customerName`)
 GROUP BY 
DAY(`Extent1`.`triggerDate`)) AS `GroupBy1`) AS `Project1`
 ORDER BY 
`Project1`.`C2` ASC}
```

When i run the query directly in  MySQL i get this error

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that                                                                                                                                                              ht syntax to use near '{SELECT
`Project1`.`C3` AS `C1`,
`Project1`.`C2`,
`Project1`.`C1` AS `C3`
FROM' at line 1
```

So i am wondering if anyone know about this issue and how to get past it. The MySQL server is running on version (5.1.41)

Comment: I agree with the error, with that given SQL, so this may be a bug with the Linq to MySQL provider

Comment: Yes, im assuming the same that its a bug with the provider.

Comment: Which connector (and version) are you using?

Comment: I installed mysql-connector-net-6.9.5.msi then mysql-for-visualstudio-1.2.3.msi, then started vs and connected to the db and built the ADO.NET entity model (edmx file). the most perculiar is that the query works with only one element in the select but i need both :/

Comment: Odd. 6.8.4 appears to be the latest release according to the [MySQL website](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.0.html). It may be a version mismatch could be causing this, or a bug in the development branch, which you might be better off [reporting directly to them](http://bugs.mysql.com/)

Comment: Mine says 6.8.5
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/ you need to check the latest, that link is to previous

Comment: NuGet says 6.9.6 https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data.Entity/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is definitely caused by a [bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=60589) that is still present in the latest ([6.9.6](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data.Entity/), as per my comment) version of MySql.Data.Entity.

Unfortunately most `group by` clauses in LINQ cannot be used with MySql because of this bug.

In the latest version, the bug appears to create fictious columns in the SQL statement, and those columns are not at all present in the schema.

There are two <strike>feasible</strike> painful solutions at the moment: 1) switch to NHibernate, which has a decent LINQ-to-HQL support, or 2) materialize the query using `.AsEnumerable` or `.ToList`

Update: on 7/14/2015 version 6.9.7 was released. According to [changelog](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/connector-net/en/connector-net-news-6-9-7.html), the issue might not have been fixed yet

Comment: The bug is still there in version 6.9.9. I fixed this with a workaround. I used database view to generate grouped result.